# Mostrar Panel en celda DataGridView, sin sobrepasar los límites, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, optimización, datagrid, visual-studio-2010

Estoy mostrando un `Panel` que contiene un pequeño `DataGridView` en el, al hacer click en la celda de otro `DataGridView`.

He logrado hacerlo, obteniendo la coordenada de cada celda donde quiero mostrar el panel, y he calculado donde debe mostrarse, pero lo he hecho básicamente a fuerza bruta.

Cuando me refiero a que no sobrepase los límites, quiero decir que si doy click en alguna esquina del final del `DataGridView` el panel se muestre de forma correcta en una posición que no sobre salga del tamaño completo del `DataGridView`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void dgrid_planificacion_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     //Obetengo las coordenadas de la celda seleccionada. 
     Rectangle coordenada = dgrid_planificacion.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dgrid_planificacion.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dgrid_planificacion.CurrentCell.RowIndex, false);

    if (e.ColumnIndex > 1)
    {
        int ancho_grid, alto_grid, ancho_panel, alto_panel, ancho_celda, alto_celda;

        ancho_grid = dgrid_planificacion.Size.Width; 
        alto_grid = dgrid_planificacion.Size.Height;

        ancho_panel = panel_detalle.Size.Width; 
        alto_panel = panel_detalle.Size.Height;

        ancho_celda = coordenada.Location.X; 
        alto_celda = coordenada.Location.Y;  

        if (!Convert.ToString(dgrid_planificacion.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value).Equals(""))
        {

              //Ezquina superior izquierda. 
              if (( alto_panel + alto_celda ) < ( alto_grid ) && ( ancho_panel + ancho_celda ) < ancho_grid)
              {
                   //El numero 14 es para indicarle la posicion que tendra el panel en el eje Y (comienzo de la celda) 
                   panel_detalle.Location = new Point(( ancho_celda + dgrid_planificacion.Location.X ),
                                                         ( alto_celda + dgrid_planificacion.Location.Y ) + 14);

                   panel_detalle.BringToFront(); //Para que el panel este por arriba del DatagridView  Planificacion
                   panel_detalle.Visible = true;
               }
               else
                  //Esquina Superior Derecha
                  if (( alto_panel + alto_celda ) < ( alto_grid ))
                  {
                      //El numero 2 es para controlar la sepacion del panel de la celda.
                      panel_detalle.Location = new Point(( ancho_celda - ancho_panel ) + 33,
                                                             ( coordenada.Bottom ) - 2);
                      panel_detalle.BringToFront();
                      panel_detalle.Visible = true;
                   }
                    else
                       //Esquina Inferior Izquierda 
                       if (( coordenada.Bottom + alto_panel ) > ( alto_grid ) && ( ancho_panel + ancho_celda ) < ( ancho_grid ))
                       {
                           panel_detalle.Location = new Point(( ancho_celda + dgrid_planificacion.Location.X ),
                                                                 ( alto_celda - alto_panel ) + 1);
                           panel_detalle.BringToFront();
                           panel_detalle.Visible = true;
                       }
                       else //Esquina Inferior Derecha
                       {
                            //El numero 33 indicar el comienzo de la celda y mostrar el panel en esa posicion. 
                           panel_detalle.Location = new Point(( ancho_celda - ancho_panel ) + 33,
                                                                 ( alto_celda - alto_panel ));
                           panel_detalle.BringToFront();
                           panel_detalle.Visible = true;
                       }
           }
           else 
              panel_detalle.Visible = false;
       }
   }
```

**¿Cómo puedo optimizar este código?** de modo que no tenga que utilizar valores fijos en el código, ya que si en algún momento le daré otra aplicación tendría que calcular nuevamente los valores fijos, si tengo mas columnas o menos, etc.

**Nota:** Como en C# por defecto no existe un `DataGridView` anidado, he optado por hacer esto de esta manera, se que existen controles externos que contienen un Maestro `DataGridView` con muchas funcionalidades, pero no deseo utilizar uno por ahora.

Comment: ¿Quieres que haga lo mismo que el gif que pones en tu pregunta?

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza Eso es lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora, lo que se muestra en el Gif, pero si te fijas en el código tengo valores fijos en los cálculos como por ejemplo `33` , `-2` etc, y si en algún momento deseo utilizar este método en otro lado, tendria que volver a calcular que valores poner dependiendo de si el `DataGridView` es mas pequeño o mas grande que este actual, **Hay una mejor manera de hacerlo? de que forma lo harías tu?**

Comment: ¿El GridView que se muestra también tendería a cambiar?

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza no, solo me refiero a si cambio el `DataGridView` de fondo que contiene todas las columnas, Si intentara cambiar el `DataGridView` que se muestra seria un tema complicado adaptarlo a cada uso, serie una especie de `respondive design` que no existe en `WindowsForms` :(

Comment: en un rato te doy una respuesta  satisfactoria  con puntos clave acerca del tema  **responsive** que buscas.

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza de acuerdo, estaré a la espera y gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución que te ofrezco tiene cierta restricciones acerca del posicionamiento de tu DataGridview en donde este deberá estar ajustado en lo posible al inicio 0,0 de tu Form. Si por temas de necesidad no puedes hacerlo así entonces tendrás que manejar dos variables extras como fix para calcular exactamente la posición de cada celda ya que si te diste cuenta la que te devuelve es en relación al Datagridview y no del Form.

## Solucion

```
    private void dgrid_planificacion_CellClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //Obetengo las coordenadas de la celda seleccionada. 
        Rectangle coordenada = dgrid_planificacion.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dgrid_planificacion.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dgrid_planificacion.CurrentCell.RowIndex, false);

        // obtenemos el ancho y alto de una celda 
        //Asumiendo que todos tienen la misma dimension
        //De no ser asi tendras que calcular cada celda por separado
        // para dibujar correctamente tu panel 

        int widthCell = coordenada.Width;
        int heightCell = coordenada.Height;

        // asignacion de variables 
        int ancho_grid, alto_grid, ancho_panel, alto_panel, posx_celda, posy_celda;

        ancho_grid = dgrid_planificacion.Size.Width;
        alto_grid = dgrid_planificacion.Size.Height;

        ancho_panel = panel_detalle.Size.Width;
        alto_panel = panel_detalle.Size.Height;

        posx_celda = coordenada.Location.X;
        posy_celda = coordenada.Location.Y;

        // validacion de panel  con menor tamaño que gridview 
        //Como no piensas tomar  las columnas 0 y 1 aqui le agregas la diferencia de tamaño 
        // ademas agregamos un valor extra del posicionamiento central en el Cell
        if ((ancho_panel + (widthCell / 2)) > (ancho_grid - (2 * widthCell)) || (alto_panel + (heightCell / 2) ) > alto_grid)
        {
            //mensaje de alerta por ser de menor tamaño
            panel_detalle.Visible = false;
            MessageBox.Show("El GridView es muy pequeño para mostrar el panel");
            return;
        }
        else if (e.ColumnIndex > 1)  // solo coge apartir de la tercera columna la funcion
        {

            if (!Convert.ToString(dgrid_planificacion.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value).Equals(""))
            {
                 // aqui los ifs nos serviran para calcular la posicion X e Y
                int posx,posy ;

                 //si es 
                if ((alto_panel + posy_celda + (heightCell / 2)) < (alto_grid))
                    posy = posy_celda + (heightCell / 2);
                else
                    posy = posy_celda - alto_panel + (heightCell / 2);

                if ((ancho_panel + posx_celda + (widthCell / 2)) < ancho_grid)
                    posx = posx_celda + (widthCell / 2);
                else
                    posx = posx_celda - ancho_panel + (widthCell / 2);

                //codigo refactorizado
                panel_detalle.Location = new Point(posx, posy);
                panel_detalle.BringToFront();
                panel_detalle.Visible = true;
                return;
            }

        }      
        // sino cumple nada se hace false
        panel_detalle.Visible = false;

    }
```

Comment: Disculpa por la demora, ya no estaba cuando respondiste, funciona bien pero tengo esta restricción _deberá estar ajustado en lo posible al inicio 0,0 de tu Form_ ya que aquí lo coloqué en el `Form` en `0,0` solo por prueba, pero en el form real no se encuentra en esa ubicación

Comment: @J.Rodríguez  Por eso te digo que deberás manejar esas variables para corregir el calculo  cuando dibujes tu panel.  Por ejemplo si tu Data Gridview esta mas abajo cuando calcules tu ´posy´ deberás haciéndolo sumándole esa diferencia adicional. También cuando se calcule si sobre pasa o no el panel deberia sumarse ese valor (tengo duda si cambia o no la logica de esa parte asi que prueba).

Comment: ok, muchas Gracias. Saludos!